# Prove that $ \lim\limits_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z}= \infty$ and $ \lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \frac{1}{z}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Prove that $ \ \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z}= \infty \ $ and  $ \ \lim_{z \to \infty} \frac{1}{z}=0 \ $ .

**Answer:**

Let  $ z=x+iy \ $ . Then   $ \ z \to \ $ implies   that $ \ x+iy \ \to \ 0 $ , which implies $ (x,y) \to (0,0) \ $.

Now,

$ \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z} \\ = \lim_{(x,y) \to \infty} \frac{1}{x+iy} \\ = \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2} \\ = \lim_{(x,y) \to 0 } \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} -i \lim_{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \\ = \lim{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{1}{2x+2y}-i \lim{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{1}{2x+2y}  \\ =  \infty -i \infty \\ = \infty $

**Am I right ? 
Any help ?**

Comment: So this is about the *one-point* compactification of $\Bbb C$? What is the definition of $f(z)\to\infty$?

Comment: The first is a false statement. $1/z$ approaches $\infty$ on the real axis from the right, but approaches $-\infty$ on the real axis from the left. It is true however that the limit does not exist.

Comment: ... what book are you reading?

Comment: it is from  a  competitive book question of limits in complex analysis

Comment: @MANMAID The restriction $\theta\ne2k\pi$ seems ludicrous, why mention it?

Comment: You are not right.

Comment: but how ? I can not find the fault. can you reason ?

Comment: One can suspect that the crucial step $$\lim_{(x,y) \to 0 } \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}= \lim{(x,y) \to 0} \frac{1}{2x+2y}$$ which should actually read $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0) } \frac{x}{x^2+y^2}= \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{1}{2x+2y}$$ is yet again another malfeasance of the nefarious so-called "L'Hopital rule".

Answer (score 1):

If $z \rightarrow 0$, then you've been given a a sequence of complex numbers $ \{z_i\}$ having the property that all but finitely many of them are in a neighborhood of zero.  Now choose (a real number) $B > 0$.  Then for all but finitely many $z_i$, $|1/z_i| > B$.  This shows your first claim.

Now  $z \rightarrow \infty$ means that for any $B > 0$  all but finitely many of the $z_i$ have $|z_i| > B$.  Now fix $\epsilon > 0$.  You need to show that all but finitely many $z_i$ satisfy $|1/z_i| < \epsilon$.  Well, this is true for the $z_i$ such that  $|z_i|> B = 1/\epsilon$.  And that fact is true for all but finitely many of these $z_i$.